# How can I programmatically disable Secure Input?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, applescript

I use a third-party key-mapping tool on my work Mac called [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/). Recently, due to what I believe is corporate interference, it's effectively been disabled due to a macOS feature called "Secure Input" being made active. BetterTouchTool actually has detection for this, and here's what their description of the feature says:

> Secure input is a macOS security feature which can be enabled & disabled by any app. Usually this is used while password fields are active in order to prevent other apps from logging sensitive data. If secure input is enabled, BetterTouchTool can not track the keyboard events using the new implementation.
>
> Unfortunately there are some apps that don't disable secure keyboard input and keep it always on. If you have this option enabled, BetterTouchTool will automatically switch to the old keyboard shortcut implementation if secure input is active. However the advanced features (see above) won't work in that case.

Long story short... it doesn't appear the fallback option they mention is working correctly, so I'm trying to find ways to disable this "Secure Input" option. I've also noticed that another third-party app I use, [Hyper Switch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch), has stopped working as well for (I assume) the same reason. If their description is correct, and any app can indeed enable or disable the feature, I should be able to write my own app and programatically disable Secure Input. So I've downloaded Xcode but I don't really know where to begin.

Is there some way, either through Objective-C/Swift, or through Applescripts, or through any other programmatic access, to disable Secure Input globally? Is there some macOS API call to do it? Even if it's something that I have to run each time I log into the machine, that would be fine... as long as it works!

How can I programmatically disable this feature from an app?

Comment: You'd be better off figuring out which application is keeping Secure Input active and dealing with that than disabling it system-wide. See this thread for a tip on how to find out which app is the culprit: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/disable-secure-input/2410/4

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure you *can* disable it system-wide. It's usually enabled or disabled depending on if you are typing in a password field or not.

Comment: What happens if you go System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Privacy. Choose "Full Disk Access" in the left panel, unlock, and in the window to the right add and enable the apps "Terminal" and "Script Editor"? If it doesn't change anything, you can just change back, or try other applications. My idea is that those utility apps often highly depend on access to everything and uses AppleScript and Bash commands in the background. So maybe BetterTouchTools starts behave like it should if you do this, I mean.

Comment: @turingtested Script Editor, Terminal and other apps must be added to the pref pane to run a script or command which needs access. How is Full Disk Access related to Secure Input?

Comment: @Willeke Nothing, I guess... but please read the rest of the comment. The app may depend on having full disk access to behave as intended. It's something I would try anyway before trying to fix the secure input-issue.